# Selected pixel of displayed image?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am selecting some area of image in displayed imageview. Then i do some work on selected pixels of that bitmap which is displayed in imageview. But i am not able to hit those pixel which user selected. I know i have to do some pixel mapping of displayed image and actual bitmap. See images for better understanding of my problem.

User select some pixel using circular selector

[image]

After processing affected pixels are different not those which user selected

[image]

I have tried some thing like this to get accurate pixels

```
Bitmap image = EyeColorChangerActivity.getImageBitmap();

     int displayedwidht = image.getWidth();
     int displayedheight = image.getHeight();

     x = x*((float)displayedwidht/mScreenWidth);
     y = y*((float)displayedheight/mScreenHeight);
```

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to change color of selected pixels

Answer (score 0):

Set OnTouchListener on your ImageView.

Inside onTouch method of OnTouchListener use the following code to get the selected bitmap pixel.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
int x = (int) arg1.getX();
int y = (int)arg1.getY();
int pixel = mBitmap.getPixel(x, y);
// process new color for selected pixel.
    ....
//set new color to bitmap pixel

return false;
}
```